# Вывести значения из словаря словарей по ключу

Tags: python, словари

```
tovar = {
    'tovar': {
        'Кофе': {
            '300 мл - 119 руб': '119',
            '400 мл - 149 руб': '149'
        },
        'Напиток': {
            '300 мл - 119 руб': '119',
            '400 мл - 139 руб': '139'
        },
        'Сироп': {
            '300 мл - 119 руб': '119',
            '400 мл - 139 руб': '139'
        }
    },
}
```

Подскажите как вывести значения по ключу `Кофе` ?
Пробовал `print(tovar['tovar'][0])` не работает

Comment: `print(tovar['tovar']['Кофе'])`

Comment: Именно вывести текст Кофе

Comment: Тогда `print('Кофе')`

Comment: И в этом коде кстати нет ни одного массива

Comment: Вывести текст "Кофе" очень просто  - ``print("Кофе")``. Объясните четко задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, например, так:

```
print(list(tovar['tovar'])[0])
# Кофе
```

Объяснение: порядок хранения ключей словаря исторически как бы не гарантирован (хотя в последних версиях Python уже всё же гарантирован), поэтому их нельзя индексировать по номерам. Но если ключи словаря превратить в список, тогда можно взять из этого списка элемент по индексу.

И да - у вас тут не массивы, а словари трёх уровней вложенности.

Comment: Но раз порядок не гарантирован, то нет и гарантии, что первый элемент списка по индексу окажется кофе

Comment: Ошибка 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Федотов Проверьте скобки. А также я немного сократил ответ

Comment: @Федотов код в этом ответе точно работает (хотя иногда вместо «Кофе» выводит «Напиток»), значит вы что-то сломали сами у себя

Comment: @andreymal По-моему в последних версиях Python порядок всё же сохраняется, хотя и не гарантирован )

Comment: @CrazyElf в последних версиях порядок уже гарантирован, но я из вредности запускаю в Python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите вывести в итоге, но у меня есть такое предложение для решения

```
for name in tovar['tovar']:                  
    print(name + ': ')                       
    for k, v in tovar['tovar'][name].items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Этот код выведет:

```
Кофе: 
300 мл - 119 руб: 119
400 мл - 149 руб: 149
Напиток: 
300 мл - 119 руб: 119
400 мл - 139 руб: 139
Сироп: 
300 мл - 119 руб: 119
400 мл - 139 руб: 139
```

Comment: Мне нужно вывести вот эти слова из словаря Кофе Напиток Сироп

Comment: @Федотов изменила ответ. Сам вывод можете форматировать как вам нужно